# How to assign groups of transactions at the same time in GnuCash?

Tags: gnucash

I'm trying to use GnuCash and I imported the transactions from the last two years.

However, it looks like I have to assign each one of them manually, even if I have like 20 transactions or more for the most common ones, where I could save time by doing them in a single shot.

How can I do a "search and assign" or bulk assignments? I cannot even select multiple transactions at the same time.